# How to close the contourplot3D from top?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, interpolation, data

I received a very nice solution by Chip Hurst to make my 3DContourPlots smooth and closed in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcx0r7s4khtzpmm/DataEta2.csv?dl=0). Now I have another problem that is simpler but I still want to know the ideas of the others. The data that I am working with is provided in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tr07u964ftm37pl/DataEta1.csv?dl=0). I want to create 3DContourPlots  out of this data and then close the plot from the top.

So First I read the data and make an interpolation function out of it

```
    η2Data = Import["DataEta2.csv"];
funη2 = Interpolation[η2Data];
```

Then, using the following command, I make a 3D contourplot out of it

```
p11 = ContourPlot3D[
  funη2[Abs[x], Abs[y], z] == 0.52, {x, -25, 25}, {y, -25, 
   25}, {z, 0, 25}, Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> Blue, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading"]
```

Now the question is how to close it from the top surface. I was thinking that maybe adding another layer of data with zero values will do the job but I think there should be more elegant and better solutions.

Comment: Note that `"SmoothShading"` is only a theme for mesh based regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually converting a call to `ContourPlot3D` into a call to `RegionPlot3D` will do the trick.

```
RegionPlot3D[funη2[Abs[x], Abs[y], z] >= 0.52, {x, -25, 25}, {y, -25, 25}, {z, 0, 25}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! nice and tidy! Thanks